# Java - Classes with type?

Tags: java, class

```
puclic class ClassA<T> {
}
```

what is the following technique called where you can pass a class type to another class and use it withing the class for type safety? I am talking about the `<T>` after my class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics.

It is the way of typecasting your class so that referential integrity is checked at compile time instead of runtime.

The complete tutorials are at

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's called generics. Is that the whole question?